# Centre cell contents vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                                                       
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd asfsdf akku  & 5  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I centre the contents of cell 01 vertically?

Comment: use `m` (array package) not `p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three different possible solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % Only needed for the first example.
\usepackage{multirow} % Only needed for the third example.
\begin{document}

Using the vertically centered m type column: 

\begin{tabular}{ m{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd asfsdf akku  & 5  \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Using three different rows for the text in the first column:

\begin{tabular}{ p{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd\\
  asfsdf   & 5\\
  akku   \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Using multirow:

\begin{tabular}{ p{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd asfsdf akku  & \multirow{3}{*}{5}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can  use `multirow` with a single cell, but you have to count the number of *lines* in this cell, on order to vertically centre its contents. Note that you can use decimal numbers to fine-tune the placement.

Alternatively, use the `m{...}` column type for the left column (requires loading `array`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd asfsdf akku & 5 \\
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd asfsdf akku & \multirow{3}{*}{5}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be using the *multirow* package (But it requires you to split cell on the left into three cells and putting the text of the right cell into a *multirow*-cell that spans over three rows).
A working example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                     \usepackage{multirow}                                                                                                
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.1\textwidth}l }
  gdgd & \multirow{3}{*}{5} \\ 
  asfsdf \\ 
  akku \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

A little explanation on the code:

```
gdgd & \multirow{3}{*}{5} \\
```

Inserts *gdgd* as the first entry of the first row and an *multirow*-cell that spans over three rows (the first parameter) inherits the width of the original column (second parameter set as *) and contains the text "5" (last parameter). \\ indicates the linebreak

```
asfsdf \\
```

Inserts *asfsdf* into the first entry of the second line. Another entry in this line is not necessary because of the *multirow*-cell above.